Minimal polynomial of $T / U$ times minimal polynomial of $T|_U$ is a polynomial multiple of the minimal polynomial of $T$
The following is exercise 5.B.25 form Linear Algebra Done Right, fourth edition by Sheldon Axler (https://linear.axler.net/LADR4e.pdf)

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional, $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ that is invariant under $T$.
(a) Prove that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is a polynomial of the minimal polynomial of the quotient operator $T / U$.
(b) Prove that
$$
(\text{minimal polynomial of } T|_U) \times (\text{minimal polynomial of } T / U)
$$
is a polynomial multiple of the minimal polynomial of $T$.

I was able to prove part (a), but have been struggling with part (b). I understand why intuitively it should be true, but my work so far hasn't sufficed to show it. See my attempt below:

Let $q := (\text{minimal polynomial of } T|_U)$ and $s := (\text{minimal polynomial of } T / U)$, and let $p$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$.
With $qs \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{F})$ and $p \neq 0$, the division algorithm says there exist unique polynomials $t, r \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{F})$ such that
$$
qs = pt + r
$$
where $\deg r < \deg p$. We want to show that $r = 0$ so that we get $qs(T) = 0$.
By result 5.31 in the text, $p$ is a polynomial multiple of $q$, which means there exists a monic, nonzero $d_1 \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{F})$ such that
$$
p = qd_1
$$
By part (a) of this exercise, there exists a monic, nonzero $d_2 \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{F})$ such that
$$
p = sd_2
$$
The above three equations imply
$$
p^2 = (qs)(d_1d_2) = (pt)(d_1d_2) + r(d_1d_2)
$$
This equation implies
\begin{align}
p(T)p(T) = 0 = r(T)(d_1d_2)(T)
\end{align}
I wanted to end up with $r(T) = 0$, which would force $r = 0$ since $\deg r < \deg p$. But I cannot just get rid of $(d_1d_2)(T)$ unless I know it's invertible. Does anyone have suggestions on how to proceed/revise the argument?

Consider the action $q(T)\circ s(T)$ on a vector in $V$.

You can show directly that $qs(T) = 0$ by first proving that the image of $s(T)$ is contained in $U$.

Thanks for the suggestion. I have been trying to show this, but I'm not able to. What I know is that $U$ must be invariant under $s(T)$, but that only tells me for any $u \in U$, we have $s(T)u \in U$. But what about the $v \in V$ not in $U$?

What do you think of this: we can show $\text{range} \ s(T) \subseteq U$ by showing that for any $v \in V$, $s(T)v - 0 \in U$. This is equivalent to showing $(s(T)v + U) \cap (0 + U) \neq \emptyset$. We have that $(s(T)v + U) \cap (0 + U) = s(T / U)(v + U) \cap U$. Since $s$ is the minimal polynomial of $T / U$ we have that $s(T / U)(v + U) = 0 + U = U$. It's clear that $U \cap U$ is nonempty, so we're done. Is my reasoning here correct?

Yes, that is correct.
